# Postfix split domain setup

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, zimbra

I need to have a split domain setup on Postfix.  This is [possible with Zimbra](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Split_Domain) which uses Postfix as described here:

> If delivering to a single secondary mail system, configure a catchall on the domain to         deliver mail to a secondary mail transport if users for the same domain reside on the second system.
>
> ```
>   zmpov cd example.com
>   zmprov md example.com zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @example.com zimbraMailCatchAllForwardingAddress @example.com zimbraMailTransport smtp:mail.example.com:25
> ```
>
> Mail for Zimbra recipients on the primary system to @example.com will be delivered Zimbra mailboxes. Any address that does not exist on the Zimbra system will be routed to the secondary mail transport. This configuration will likely work with 4.5.x, but it has not been tested.

How can I achieve this in Postfix?

Answer (score 1):

Zimbra is not an MTA; it uses postfix as its MTA component.

Hence, anything Zimbra can do, postfix can too.

I don't understand your question as it is not related to postfix; restate it so it deals with SMTP terms.

Comment: I want **any** email address that is not on postfix to be delivered to a secondary mail transport, depending on the domain.  Just like the instructions for zimbra above state.

Comment: relay_domains = other.domain1, other.domain2

Comment: My "local" users are actually in ldap (on exchange), so already by default, the email is relayed to them.  I already have a relay_domains file that lists all the domains we manage.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html

I was going to setup Postfix like this as well, migrating from a Qmail server. With 14 domains and having issues with the Qmail setup, it was easier to go with Zimbra.